# ArrayAdapter with Fragments switching for items not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I need top develop a ListView where item is a fragment (FRONT) which on click flips to another fragment (BACK).

I have made a custom adapter where I am populating each item of the list (in getView) with the fragment. upon click, I am then replacing the FRONT View with the BACK view. This works fine if there is only one item buut starts behaving randomly, understandably, when there are multiple items as the onClick ALWAYS flips the top most fragment of the list.

Is there a way I can listen, identify and do my flip animation to individual items of the list?

Following is my code for the custom, adapter I wrote

```
public class CustomCardAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements OnClickListener, OnBackStackChangedListener{

    private int textViewResourceId;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> list;
    private FragmentManager fm;

    private Handler mHandler;
    private boolean mShowingBack = false;


    public CustomCardAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> list) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        mContext = context;
        this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        this.list = list;
        this.fm = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = convertView;

        if(rowView == null)
            rowView = mInflater.inflate(textViewResourceId, parent, false);

        rowView.setOnClickListener(this);
        rowView.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
        rowView.setId(position);


        fm.beginTransaction()
          .add(R.id.container, new CardFrontFragment(list.get(position)))
          .commit();

        fm.addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FlipCard(v);

    }



    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        mShowingBack = (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0);

    }

    private void FlipCard(View view){
        if(mShowingBack){
            fm.popBackStack(view.getTag().toString(),0);
            return;
        }

        mShowingBack = true;

        fm.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out
                                , R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out)
            .replace(R.id.container,new CardBackFragment("Advertise Here","describe here"))
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
    }
}
```

Please help me and tell me what needs to be changed or what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple Views with R.id.container ID on your View hierarchy.

When you call

```
.replace(R.id.container,new CardBackFragment("Advertise Here","describe here"))
```

This will replace the first View with R.id.container ID, or the first View on the list...

I don't think fragments are the best option to do what you want, you may use a ViewSwitcher or just a FrameLayout with 2 Views and animate the transition between them...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just have a frame layout with both fragments as a row, but set visibility to invisible/visible and then perform the animation?

Comment: this was something I considered but then stumbled across the card flip example and went the fragment route. Guess using two view would have required me more work on animators which was a new territory.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of onClick, you should use onListItemClick.

If it's working, but always flips the topmost item, the onClick listener must not be identifying the list item, but the list view.

I have not tried this in code, so far it is just a suggestion.

Comment: the issue here is more around how to uniquely identify a clicked fragment in the dynamic list as the fragmentManager.replace requires the fragment id.